# Find the Area of a Shaded Region using Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hello, this problem is giving me a lot of trouble. I'm confused as to what I should make my domain of integration. I understand that the larger circle would stretch to x = 30 and the smaller circle goes to x = 10.

Comment: The white area in the first quadrant is the curve for $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi/2$.  Call that area $a_1$.  Call the area under the curve from $\theta=\pi$ to $\theta=5\pi/3$ $a_2$.  The area you seek is $2(a_2-a_1)$.

Comment: Isn't it that you only have to calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} r\,d\theta$?

Comment: The area under a curve in polar coordinates is $a = 1/2 \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} r^2 d\theta$.  If you do a direct integration for the entire range you will get some regions that are counted twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$r=20cos(\theta)-10$$

as Biswajit Banerjee pointed out the area under a curve in polar coordinates is $a = 1/2 \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} r^2 d\theta$

so
$$r^2=400cos^2(\theta)-400cos(\theta)+100$$

and the half of the area under the inner curve is
$$a1=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/3}r^2d\theta = -25 (3 \sqrt{3}-2\pi)$$
and half of the area under the outside curve is
$$a2=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi}^{5\pi/3}r^2d\theta = 25 (3 \sqrt{3}+4\pi)$$

The complete area in yellow is then :
$$a=2(a2-a1) = 50 (6 \sqrt{3}+2\pi)$$